# Why does this loop 7 times instead of 5?

Tags: c#, loops

The book says the correct answer is 7, but I count 5?

"How many times will this loop?"

```cs
int j = 2;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i = i * 2)
{
    j = j - 1;
    while (j < 25)
    {
        j = j + 5;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me?

To get to 25 it would loop 5 times, not 7? 5, 10, 15, 20, 25…
I'm missing where they're getting 7 from

[image]

Comment: Looks like a great opportunity for you to practice with a debugger. Just step through the code and watch how many times it executes the loop body, keeping track of the loop variable to understand why. (And for future reference, there's no reason to go around insulting a whole class of people just to express your own failings.) Also, please make sure you a) understand which loop your book is describing, and b) you make clear in your question which loop that is.

Comment: i don't consider myself a whole class xD but good idea thanks, i'll put it in ide and step it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `i` increments by double it's value and `64 * 2 = 128` and `128 is > 100`.

So 7 times:
`1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64`

Don't be afraid to fiddle if you don't have access to an IDE readily available: https://dotnetfiddle.net/#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int j = 2;
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i = i * 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i=" + i);
            j = j - 1;
            while (j < 25)
            {
                j = j + 5;
                Console.WriteLine("j=" + j);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OHHH. I was focusing on the wrong loop. thanks that makes sense! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For the outer loop i would go through the values `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]`.
Then inside each loop j would be changed to the values;

```
 1 => 1, [6, 11, 16, 21, 26],
 2 => 25,
 4 => 24, [29],
 8 => 28,
 16 => 27,
 32 => 26,
 64 => 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The question as you've written it is not very clear as there are *multiple* loops here. It may be that this is a problem with the *original* question you got so possibly not your fault<sup>(a)</sup>.

If you make a slight modification to the code to print out when certain events happen, you'll see the detail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int j = 2;
    printf("initial j: %d\n", j);
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i = i * 2) {
        printf("LOOP-I i: %d\n", i);
        j = j - 1;
        printf("decremented j: %d\n", j);
        while (j < 25) {
            j = j + 5;
            printf("LOOP-J plus5'ed j: %d\n", j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this (annotated on the right with loop counts) is:

```
                            iLoop jLoop
                            ----- -----
initial j: 2
LOOP-I i: 1                     1
decremented j: 1
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 6                  1
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 11                 2
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 16                 3
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 21                 4
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 26                 5
LOOP-I i: 2                     2
decremented j: 25
LOOP-I i: 4                     3
decremented j: 24
LOOP-J plus5'ed j: 29                 6
LOOP-I i: 8                     4
decremented j: 28
LOOP-I i: 16                    5
decremented j: 27
LOOP-I i: 32                    6
decremented j: 26
LOOP-I i: 64                    7
decremented j: 25
```

There are seven `LOOP-I` outputs and six `LOOP-J` outputs - the latter being slightly different to your assumption of five, since the decrementing of `j` within the `i` loop brings it below `25` once more, so the `j` loop will iterate one last time.

If the answer they give is seven, then they're almost certainly talking about the outer `i` loop. From a purist's point of view, the answer to the question "How many times will this loop?" is clearly 13 (seven for the `i` loop and six for the `j` one).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> However, I suspect you've misunderstood the question. From the (not quite complete) image you posted (inside the border below), and an educated guess as to what the rest of the question is, it appears to be asking:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| Here are a few loops.  Write down if each lo|op will
| eventually end. If it's going to end, how ma|ny
+---------------------------------------------+
  times will it loop?
```

In other words, it wants you to analyse *each* loop, in which case the *two* answers would be yes/seven for the outer `i` loop and yes/six for the inner `j` one.